# Connect two cubes without creating overlapping edges/faces

Tags: modeling

I were trying to make an extremely simple table model like this:

[image]

I made this without problem:

[image]

But then I got stuck having a hard time figuring out how to continue.

My first idea was to duplicate the top face, move it down and create side faces:

[image]

Then the new vertices were not on the side and the edges were overlapping, which wasn't what I wanted:

[image]

Perhaps I could've cut the side first?

[image]

But I don't know how to cut along the top edge, nor how to make the exact same cut on the other side.

What's the better way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried just sliding an edge loop along both sides and then equaling them out by scaling along the Z axis and pressing 0 ?

This would give you control over both sides and you can adjust the height to be whatever you would like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To follow your approach, you could:

- <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> to constrain to the horizontal and <kbd>Z</kbd> to cut through.. create loops on both sides,
- In Face Mode, Select the inside faces, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>  Edge menu > *Bridge Edge Loops*

[image]

But, if your desk is mainly symmetrical, I would make only one side, and work on that, under a Mirror modifier, with 'Merge' checked.

Comment: Oh, that's clever :). *Bridge Edge Loops* removes the original faces to prevent non-manifold geo, never knew that.

Comment: @JachymMichal   One of Blender's many little Easter Eggs  :)